# how can we clear this error Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, .net

When I was run my dotnet program am getting this " Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'querySelectorAll'"? can any one pls resolve this ..

am getting this error for each and every program those are already run successful.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` exists since [IE8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304115%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This error is generating due to the low internet explorer . You should use Google Chrome or Internet Explorer 9. The low level internet browser cannot suuport run time conversion of jscript.

File >> Browse With >> Google Chrome >> Set as Default

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this error when Internet Explorer was running in compatibility mode / quirks mode as well. If you're encountering this error in a development environment, your browser may be rendering the page in compatibility mode due to Internet Explorer > Tools > Compatibility View Settings > Display intranet sites in Compatibility View. Adding an X-UA-Compatible header may also help encourage the browser to render your page in standards mode.